# javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: jsf-2, myfaces

```
May 21, 2012 6:48:06 PM org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer initFaces
SEVERE: An error occured while initializing MyFaces: javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory



May 21, 2012 6:48:09 PM com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/login.jsp]
com.sun.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /login.jsp: Error Traced[line: 1] The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.




May 21, 2012 6:48:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
com.sun.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /login.jsp: Error Traced[line: 1] The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
```

Comment: Are you mixing JSF 2.0 and Facelets 1.1.x? Facelets is bundled with JSF jars. Just remove facelets jar from your classpath, because it is no longer necessary.

Comment: thank you finally it's work but how can it work with java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory

Comment: if i create a new page called welcome.xhtml and try to run it , it doesn't work why?